# it not work when I use command telnet on my phone

Tags: telnet

It has no response when I use command:

```
telnet taobao.com 80
```

I use termux.apk on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
telnet
```

And after

```
open taobao.com 80
```

If cursor is blinking indefinitely, the port is open and listening. Otherwise no.